# How to check if today is Monday in Python

Tags: python, datetime

How would I write a statement that says:

```
If today is Monday, then run this function.
```

My thoughts are:

```
if datetime.now().day == Monday:
     run_report()
```

But I know this is not the right way to do it. How would I properly do this?

Comment: This is something you could easily work out yourself, by reading the documentation to see what `day` returns, or even trying it yourself in the shell.

Comment: @Alexander in that case, you can edit the duplicate list yourself and add your findings (I did that for you). Maybe you're not aware of this relatively new SE feature (with that one you can remove my "unfit" link and leave yours)

Comment: @Alexander specially for you: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355666/what-should-i-do-if-i-feel-that-the-original-question-of-the-duplicate-isnt-the

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use [`date.weekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) like this:

```
from datetime import date

# If today is Monday (aka 0 of 6), then run the report
if date.today().weekday() == 0:
    run_report()
```

Comment: Perfect. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 16):

```
import datetime as dt

dt.date.today().isoweekday() == 1  # 1 = Monday, 2 = Tues, etc.
```

Comment: I think that Monday is 0.

Comment: Not for `isoweekday`. Return the day of the week represented by the date.
Monday == 1 ... Sunday == 7

Comment: You are right I get confused with `weekday`. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 5):

Both `datetime.date` and `datetime.datetime`
objects have a `today` method that return respectively a `Date` and a `Datetime` object.

Which both have a `weekday` and `isoweekday` methods.
`weekday` count from Monday = 0, while `isoweekday` count from Monday = 1:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
if date.today().weekday() == 0:
    # it is Monday
if datetime.today().isoweekday() == 1:
   # it is Monday
```

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday)